# Android DatePickerDialog Year

Tags: android, dialog, calendar, picker

I have a question for you that will be easy. I have a DatePickerDialog to select the day, month and year. Now I would like to receive the default next year, not the current one. I tried to insert + 1 but it is not the desired result. thanks

```
public void chooseDate2(View v) {
    new DatePickerDialog(Inserisci_en_us.this, d2,
                          dateAndTime.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                         dateAndTime.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                          dateAndTime.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))
      .show();
  }
  private void updateLabel2() {
      scadenza.setText(fmtDateAndTime.format(dateAndTime.getTime()));           
  }
  DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener d2=new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        dateAndTime.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
      dateAndTime.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
      dateAndTime.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
      updateLabel2();
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want the next year as a default year when you open your date picker, right? I know you mentioned adding 1, but I guess you did it wrong. Just do the following:

```
Calenar c = Calendar.getInstance();
new DatePickerDialog(Inserisci_entrate_uscite.this, d2,
                      c.get(Calendar.YEAR) + 1,
                     dateAndTime.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                      dateAndTime.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))
  .show();
```

This should return the next year even if many dialogs are opened. (If the dateAndTime is the current date).

Comment: so, if the dialog is opened several times a year will be added each time, it should always display the default (for example 2015). When you start the label of Activity of default should display the date with the next anno.Ora displays the current year.

Comment: Ok I see, you can always get a new calendar instance, for example:

Comment: ok, now the problem is that the start should appear next year, that is, set the calendar for next year:`dateAndTime.set(Calendar.YEAR, year)`;